How to Find the Average Distance/Area Between a Truncated Cone and a Plane
I have been given a truncated cone that lies along the z axis (positioned so the origin is where the tip would have been) and am trying to find the average $\frac{L}{A}$, where L is the distance from a point on the cones surface to the plane and A is the projected surface area on the plane, of the slanted portion of the cone. Image of the System. I was having trouble because as you along the y axis not only does the length to the plane change but so too does the area of the projection. My initial idea was to take advantage of the symmetry of the cone and use only the slice on the positive yz plane.
I came up with equations of $z=my+h_2$ for L and $A=\pi y^2$ for A. I'm unsure if this simplification is valid for the area as it seems incorrect to decrease the dimensions of only half of the problem but the units end up being correct. From there I used the equation of for the average $$\frac{L}{A}=\frac{1}{r_2-r_1}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\frac{my+h_2}{\pi y^2}dy$$ Which can be pretty easily integrated to
$$\frac{L}{A}=\frac{1}{\pi (r_2-r_1)}(mln(\frac{r_2}{r_1})-(\frac{h_2}{r_2}-\frac{h_2}{r_1}))$$ But I have no clue if my method is correct
Thanks for taking a look!

Which area does $A$ represent exactly for a given length $L$?
